# How to return position of click event in Meteor.js

Tags: jquery, meteor

In a meteor.js app, I am trying to return the position of a click using jQuery's .position().

If I use `event` or `this`, I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined`.

If I use `$( event.currentTarget )`, it returns `0`, since that defines the element that was clicked.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  // Doesn't work
  'click .target': function (event) {
    posY = $(event).position().top; // Undefined error
    console.log( posY ) 
  },

  // also doesn't work
  'click .target': function (event) {
    var $this = $( event.currentTarget );
    posY = $this.position().top; 
    console.log( posY ) // Returns 0
  }
});
```

In straight jQuery, I would do this:

```
$( '.target' ).click( function (e) { 
    var posY = $(this).position().top;
    console.log( posY )
});
```

My question is, how do I access the same `this` in Meteor?

Comment: Don't know how to do what you want to achieve, but you can create straight jQuery event, in rendered function(which works like $(document).ready.

Comment: `event.currentTarget` refers to the element handling the event, `event.target` refers to the element that originated the event. I don't know jQuery, but maybe `event.target` works for you?

Comment: @PeppeL-G that works perfectly! Want to make that an answer, and I'll give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.target` instead of `event.currentTarget`.